# React - Close dropdown menu when clicking on the window

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a dropdown menu that opens correctly, you can click and it scrolls you to the right section. 
I also implemented that on clicking on the button again the dropdown will close.

I am now trying to implement that on click outside of the menu the dropdown would also close.

At the moment the best solution I found was to add a click event listener on the window.

This causes a problem which is when you click to open the dropdown, it will directly close it. This is why I added a new state so I can add a condition, but this doesn't work.

Could someone please describe what would be the best way in React to do that ?

Thanks in advance

```
class Explore extends Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    visible: false,
    hide: false
  }

  this.whyRef = React.createRef()
  this.overviewRef = React.createRef()

  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.closeMenu);
  // if(this.state.hide === true) window.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
}

toggleMenu = () => {
  if(!this.state.visible){
    this.setState({ visible: true, hide: true });
  } else {
    this.setState({ visible: false, hide: false});
  }
}

closeMenu = () => {
  this.setState({ visible: false });
}

scrollTo = (ref) => {
  window.scrollBy({
      top:ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref.current).getBoundingClientRect().top - 200,
      behavior: "smooth"   // Optional, adds animation
  })
}

render() {
  const { visible, hide } = this.state

  return (

      <Dropdown
        visible={visible}
        onClick={this.toggleMenu}
        trigger={['click']} overlay={
        <Menu>
          <Menu.Item key="1"
            onClick={() => this.scrollTo(this.whyRef)}>
            <Icon icon={u1F427} /> <strong>WHY</strong>
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="2" onClick={() => this.scrollTo(this.overviewRef)}>
            <Icon icon={u1F30D} /> 30,000 Feet
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
      }>
      <Button style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
        size="small">
        <strong className="text-grey clickable">
          <Icon icon={infoCircle} size={14}/> SECTIONS
        </strong>
      </Button>
      </Dropdown>
}
```

Comment: I figured out that I can select the body excepted of my dropdown and I can therefore add a relevant method to close the dropdown.

I added in the constructor:
    `document.body.addEventListener('click', 
    this.closeDropdown);`

And added a method:
     `closeDropdown = e => {
     const noClose = '.dropdown';
     if(!e.target.matches(noClose)){
      this.setState({ visible: false});
    }
  }`

But remains a bug when clicking on the dropdown to close it, it will always open it again. Its probably due to the fact that the className wasn't selected properly

Answer (score 3):

You could try to replace `onClick` with `onFocus` to open dropdown and add `onBlur` for close dropdown. `onFocus` will trigger when the element is clicked and `onBlur` will trigger when "unfocusing" (clicking outside).
Also `tabIndex` attribute/prop is needed for focus/blur to work on non input type elements.
And i think you are getting `state` wrong. Replace `visible={visible}` with `visible={this.state.visible}` 
And i removed `trigger={['click']}` as you commented out `eventListener` for it.

and code would look something like this:

```
toggleMenu = () => {
 this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
}

....
....

<Dropdown
  visible={this.state.visible}
  onFocus={this.toggleMenu}
  onBlur={this.toggleMenu}
  tabIndex="0"
  overlay={
  ....
  ....
</Dropdown>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In fact I am using Ant Design as library, and trying to use the `Dropdown` component props. The prop `onVisibleChange` is replacing the `onClick` so I guess I do not need it. The `trigger={['click]} is also needed and it is not related to the eventlistener I have commented out. Fot the `visible` state I do not not need to pass`this.state.visible` as I destructured the code `const { visible } = this.state. Somehow your code is working but I am not sure it is the right way to use it and not use the `Dropdown` component props.

Comment: In fact just removing `trigger={[click]}` is doing the job. Only small bug persisting now is when you open and close dropdown menu clicking on the button, you cannot open it again without clicking outside of the button as it keeps selected.

Comment: @Fabian Sorry I am not familiar with Ant Design, can't help.